# how to add certain number of whitespaces to StringBuilder?

Tags: c#

How can I add certain number (between 1 and 100) of whitespaces to StringBuilder?

```
StringBuilder nextLine = new StringBuilder();
string time = Util.CurrentTime;
nextLine.Append(time);
nextLine.Append(/* add (100 - time.Length) whitespaces */);
```

What would be "ideal" solution? `for` loop is ugly. I can also create array where `whitespaces[i]` contains string which contains exactly `i` whitespaces, but that would be pretty long hardcoded array.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [`StringBuilder.Append(char,int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxyxbz2e.aspx) method, which repeats the specified Unicode character a specified number of times:

```
nextLine.Append(time);
nextLine.Append(' ', 100 - time.Length);
```

Better yet, combine both appends into a single operation:

```
nextLine.Append(time.PadRight(100));
```

This would append your `time` string, followed by `100 - time.Length` spaces.

**Edit**: If you’re only using the `StringBuilder` to construct the padded time, then you can do away with it altogether:

```
string nextLine = time.PadRight(100);
```

Comment: Creating an intermediate string defeats somewhat the purpose of the StringBuilder, no?

Comment: @dtb: I was assuming that the `StringBuilder` is being used to construct a substantially longer string that the padded `time`. If it isn’t, then a simple `time.PadRight(100)` would obviate the need for the `StringBuilder` in the first place.

Comment: In that case, I would go with `nextLine.Append(time.PadRight(100))`. That said, if you really needed to add the spaces by themselves (and not to pad a string), then dtb’s `StringBuilder.Append(char,int)` would probably be preferable over the `new string(char,int)`.

Comment: Sigh… since downvoters seem to be having a field day, I’m editing my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [StringBuilder.Append overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxyxbz2e.aspx) that takes a `char` and an `int`:

```
nextLine.Append(' ', 100 - time.Length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use PadLeft -

```
nextLine.Append(String.Empty.PadLeft(' ', 100 - time.Length));
```