# Adding whitespaces to a string in C#

Tags: c#, string

I'm getting a `string` as a parameter.

Every string should take 30 characters and after I check its length I want to add whitespaces to the end of the string.
E.g. if the passed string is 25 characters long, I want to add 5 more whitespaces.

The question is, how do I add whitespaces to a string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java

Comment: I think this question relates to the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870037/how-to-add-certain-number-of-whitespaces-to-stringbuilder Greetings,

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use [String.PadRight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for this.

> Returns a new string that left-aligns the characters in this string by padding them with spaces on the right, for a specified total length.

For example:

```
string paddedParam = param.PadRight(30);
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`String.PadRight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for this;

> Returns a new string of a specified length in which the end of the
>   current string is padded with spaces or with a specified Unicode
>   character.

```
string s = "cat".PadRight(10);
string s2 = "poodle".PadRight(10);

Console.Write(s);
Console.WriteLine("feline");
Console.Write(s2);
Console.WriteLine("canine");
```

Output will be;

```
cat       feline
poodle    canine
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/z0oy0E).

> PadRight adds spaces to the right of strings. It makes text easier to
>   read or store in databases. Padding a string adds whitespace or other
>   characters to the beginning or end. PadRight supports any character
>   for padding, not just a space.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`String.PadRight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s.aspx) which will space out a string so it is as long as the `int` provided.

```
var str = "hello world";
var padded = str.PadRight(30);
// padded = "hello world                   "
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use Padding in C#

eg

```
  string s = "Example";
  s=s.PadRight(30);
```

I hope It will resolve your problem.